# Spring boot Web services - WSDL generation

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have followed this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/ by Spring and works fine, however, I do not get part of it.
The demo application takes an XSD file and generates a WSDL from it. My understanding is that XSD files are a subset of the WSDLs. How can the Spring framework figure out the missing information based on the XSD files only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct the `WSDL` contains more information. But from the `xsd` some basic information is extracted like the name of the request that can be served with `SOAP` and the parameters it should accept.

Then Spring uses annotation processing for some more information that needs to be appended in the `WSDL`

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request)
```

Spring also extracts information from bean configuration which needs to be appended in `WSDL`

```
@Bean(name = "countries")
public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CountriesPort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(countriesSchema);
    return wsdl11Definition;
}
```

Everything else that is contained in `WSDL` and not configured in your project, is applied as default configuration from Spring it self, if it is allowed to do so for some elements.

1 reason for why this approach is used, is that with the `xsd` you have both some configurations for `WSDL` that can be used but also you have a way of creating the `java` domain objects which are needed so that requests and responses can be handled.